# What is the best pactices or approach to pass an error from nested function to centralize error handler

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I am using the express.js framework to built my application. I need concrete and best practices opinion to manage to handle the error centralize.

I am developing a multi-lingual application, so at the initial level, I thought it would manage also from the backend side but later on, I realized, and manage only a single language in the backend.

Here I can pass the error Key and it will return the full error message through res.__('errKey') function.

> AuthController.js

```
async signIn(req, res) {
    const { deviceMetadata, locationMetadata } = req;
    const { app: requestApp } = req.headers;
    const { email = null, password = null } = req.body;

    if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0 || email.length === 0 || password.length === 0) {
      return _400('errEmptyEmailOrPassword');
    }

    if (email.length === 0) {
      return _400('errEmptyEmail');
    }

    if (password.length === 0) {
      return _400('errEmptyPassword');
    }

    const isValid = schemaValidator(signIn, req.body);
    if (!isValid.valid) {
      logger.error(isValid);
      return _400('errInvalidEmailOrPassword');
    }

    const userIden = await authService.verifyEmailAndHash({
      email,
      password,
      deviceMetadata,
      locationMetadata,
    });

    if (userIden === 'errInvalidEmailAndHash') {
      logger.error(userIden);
      return _401('errInvalidEmailAndHash');
    }

    const objGrantedToken = await tokenService.grantToken({
      userIden,
    });

    if (objGrantedToken === 'errHttpBadRequest') {
      return _400('httpBadRequest');
    }

    return commonHelper.successResponse(res, 'validEmailAndHash', objGrantedToken);
  }
}
```

> tokenService.js

```
static async verifyEmailAndHash(params) {
    const { email, password: inputHash} = params;

    const resEmail = await authDbService.verifyEmail(email);
    if (resEmail && resEmail.name && resEmail.name === 'SequelizeDatabaseError') {
      return 'errSequelizeDatabaseError';
    }

    if (resEmail.length === 0) {
      return 'errInvalidEmailAndHash';
    }

    const { id: userId = null } = resEmail[0];
    const resHash = await authDbService.getHash(userId);

    if (resHash.length === 0) {
      return 'errInvalidEmailAndHash';
    }

    const { hash: dbHash } = resHash[0];
    const isHashCompared = await AuthService.assertHash(inputHash, dbHash);
    const isValid = isHashCompared === 'validEmailAndHash' ? userId : 'errInvalidEmailAndHash';

    if (isValid === 'errInvalidEmailAndHash') {
      await authDbService.insertLoginAttempts({
        userId,
      });
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

> custom-error.js

```
class MyError extends Error {
  /**
   * @description constructor to modify the error object
   * @param {String} statusCode
   * @param  {...any} args [name, message, errorKey]
   */
  constructor(statusCode = 500, ...args) {
    const [statusName, errorKey] = args;

    super(errorKey);

    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.success = false;
    this.name = statusName;
    this.errorKey = errorKey;
  }
}
exports.MyError = MyError;
```

> customer-error-utils.js

```
const { MyError } = require('./MyError');

const objStatusName = {
  400: 'HttpBadRequest',
  401: 'HttpUnauthorized',
  403: 'HttpForbidden',
  404: 'HttpNotFound',
  409: 'HttpConflict',
  412: 'HttpPreconditionFailed',
  413: 'HttpEntityTooLarge',
  500: 'InternalServerError',
  502: 'BadGateway',
  503: 'ServiceUnavailble',
};

const objMessage = {
  400: 'Server will not process the request',
  401: 'User does not have the needed credentials',
  403: 'Service is declining to react',
  404: 'Service not found',
  409: 'Request could not have processed due to conflict',
  412: 'Request did not state the length of content,',
  413: 'Payload is too large',
  500: 'Something unexpected happens',
  502: 'Bad gateway',
  503: 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',
};

const objErrorKey = {
  400: 'errHttpBadRequest',
  401: 'errHttpUnauthorized',
  403: 'errHttpForbidden',
  404: 'errHttpNotFound',
  409: 'errHttpConflict',
  412: 'errHttpPreconditionFailed',
  413: 'errHttpEntityTooLarge',
  500: 'errInternalServerError',
  502: 'errBadGateway',
  503: 'errServiceUnavailble',
};

const _400 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[400]) => {
  throw new MyError(400, objStatusName[400], errorKey);
};
const _401 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[401]) => {
  throw new MyError(401, objStatusName[401], errorKey);
};
const _403 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[403]) => {
  throw new MyError(403, objStatusName[403], errorKey);
};
const _404 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[404]) => {
  throw new MyError(404, objStatusName[404], errorKey);
};
const _409 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[409]) => {
  throw new MyError(409, objStatusName[409], errorKey);
};
const _412 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[412]) => {
  throw new MyError(412, objStatusName[412], errorKey);
};
const _413 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[413]) => {
  throw new MyError(413, objStatusName[413], errorKey);
};
const _500 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[500]) => {
  throw new MyError(500, objStatusName[500], errorKey);
};
const _502 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[502]) => {
  throw new MyError(502, objStatusName[502], errorKey);
};
const _503 = (errorKey = objErrorKey[503]) => {
  throw new MyError(503, objStatusName[503], errorKey);
};

module.exports = {
  _400,
  _401,
  _403,
  _404,
  _409,
  _412,
  _413,
  _500,
  _502,
  _503,
};
```

> error-middlware.js

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    return res
    .status(404)
    .json({
        success: false,
        errorCode: 'errHttpNotFound',
        message: res.__('errHttpNotFound'),
    })
    .end();
});

// catch all remaining programming error
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {

    const { success, stack, name: errorName, errorKey = 'errInternalServerError' } = err;
    let { statusCode = 500 } = err;

    const objErr = {
    success: success || false,
    errorCode: errorKey,
    message: res.__(`${errorKey}`),
    };

    if (debugMode === 'on') {
    Object.assign(objErr, {
        stack,
    });
    }

    logger.error(`
    url: ${req.url}\n
    statusCode: ${statusCode}\n
    sucess: ${success}\n
    errorName: ${errorName}\n
    errorKey:${errorKey},
    stack: ${stack}
    `);

    if (
    err instanceof Error &&
    ((err.errno === 'ECONNREFUSED' && err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') ||
        (err.errno === 'ENOTFOUND' && err.code === 'ENOTFOUND'))
    ) {
    statusCode = 503;
    const address = err.message.split(' ')[err.message.split(' ').length - 1];
    Object.assign(objErr, {
        errorCode: 'errUnreachable',
        message: `${address} ${res.__('errUnreachable')}`,
    });
    return res.status(statusCode).json(objErr).end();
    }

    return res.status(statusCode).json(objErr).end();
});
```

I need more opinion and best industry-standard guidelines that how do I robust implementation of an error.

In my code, you have seen that there are so many errors that occurred at services or DB services level and pass to the controller and at last controller will call my error function. It would become more tedious and create chaining from bottom level function to top-level function.

In my above scenario and pattern, you have seen that if any database error occurred it would pass to services and then go to controller.

I see that something I have missed,  but I don't know and even I don't judge that how do I make more robust.

So I need an answer or guideline for the following questions

- How would I manage the errors centrally so I will not repeat the code?
- How to catch the error at the place where it occurred rather than passing error from DB methods > service methods > controller, and it would directly catch in centralize error handler and reduce my overhead?
- Even I don't know that current whatever the approach I have followed is legitimate or not?

Here my problem is that I am not able to leverage centralize error handler. Every time I need to catch each and every condition.

I expect good and robust guidelines so I learn and improve my codebase.

I will provide more information and scenario if anyone needs more information.

Answer (score 1):

I had a simple strategy for handling my errors.

I created some global functions responsible for the return statement.

First I create some conventional rules.

1. Any database error with 422 status code and the error message is the return.
2. Any validation error with 400 status code and the message body has two properties. Message: "bad request, reason :" the validation error reason".
3. Unauthorized requests return with 401 status code and the message is: unauthorized or invalid token
4. 404 status code when something is not found or not available at the moment with the proper message
5. 403 status code when the action is forbidden with the message: "forbidden", reason: " proper reason"

You can handle this by just one function with proper parameters. With this simple pattern I can achieve:

1. Avoid duplicate codes
2. Clean code
3. Flexible error handling for a return statement
4. Handling error localization

Of course this is not your answer but it might help.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but my pain is that when I have centalize error handler, is it good if I can throw an error from my services directly.?

Comment: Like any data not found the I don't need to wait to pass this contoller just throw an error and send the error message to frontend.

Comment: My current application is complex but the error handler mechanism is quite simple that the MyError class should throw and error amd there are predefined errors I have built.

Comment: @Dipakchavda it's ok to handle error directly in controllers. the best practice of all programming languages is: catch the errors correctly.